# AAD V2 in ASP.NET Core WebAPI with JwtBearer

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Need your help with the below problem. I'm creating a **webapi** in .netcore in VS2017, and I'm trying to use the new model of authentication with https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/.

I register the app, create the reply URL to https://localhost:44337/signin-oidc

In .netcore I have the below config

```
  "Authentication": {
    "AzureAd": {
      "AADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "Audience": "<my audience>/<Name Of The App Registered>",
      "ClientId": "<Registered App ID>",
      "Domain": "<Domain of AAD>",
      "TenantId": "<Tenant ID of AAD>"
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Now I'm testing with a Universal App, but, whenever after trying login, always send me this error:

```
Additional technical information: 
Correlation ID: a14b452f-457a-46e6-9601-67383df6ba1a 
Timestamp: 2017-05-11 09:42:56Z 
AADSTS50011: The reply address 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: '<My Application ID>'. More details: not specified
```

I already confirm the AppID in apps.dev.microsoft.com, and I have also registered the app in AAD (with different ID, I cannot control that)

This is the code of Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        Authority = Configuration["Authentication: AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication: AzureAd:TenantId"],
        Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Audience"],
        TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authentication: AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication: AzureAd:TenantId"] + "/ v2.0"
        }
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I already solve this problem. Thank you Martin for the help, the solution is similar to your recommendation.

The solution to this problem is:
On https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ you need to register a new platform as Native and keep that values.

Answer (score 2):

Your UWP App must be registred as a **native** applcation with the following reply url: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. Also you have to *grant* permission for the UWP app to call your API.

Comment: let's say I want to access with PostMan, or I publish the app into the cloud for anyone use (because this is a webapi that returns json data). I think I do not need to register all the apps that will access to my WebAPI, right? Or any app that will use my webapi must be registered? Do I need to do something to avoid that?

Comment: In your case, you have an UWP app. AFAIK, the UWP app can't receive the token that is sent to https://localhost:44337/signin-oidc when you login to your API. Thats why you have to register a native app and grant permissions to the api to it.

Comment: Hi Martin, I already had the opportunity to get the information on Postman, so, if I insert on postman the configuration with https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://outlook.com/ I have a response with a valid token, but cannot use in my requests. If I use https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://localhost:44337/ or any other page, it opens me a black page without any token. Should I be missing some part on my webapi?